# MySQL Workbench decrypt data encrypted in php using AES-128-CTR

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I am trying to decode data encrypted in PHP using AES-128-CTR in MySQL workbench and having no luck. All I get is null.

Any help would be, as always, greatly appreciated.

Workbench attempt:
I tried `@@SESSION.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-128-ctr'` but got error that it could not be set to 'aes-128-ctr'.

```
SELECT desired_column, cast(AES_DECRYPT(desired_column, '1111111111111111') as CHAR) as result from table;
```

Encryption code from php.

```
public function encryption($string){ 
    // Store the cipher method 
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR"; 

    // Use OpenSSl Encryption method 
    $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering); 
    $options = 0; 

    // Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption 
    $encryption_iv = '1111111111111111'; 

    // Store the encryption key 
    $encryption_key = "somesecretkey"; 

    // Use openssl_encrypt() function to encrypt the data 
    return openssl_encrypt($string, $ciphering, $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv); 
}
```

Comment: encrytion is not the same everywhere, other implementations hinder decryption so decode only in the same environment as the encryption

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html there is no CTR mode available in mysql, sorry.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I am at a stage where selecting a different ciphering isn't out of the question. This isn't live yet. Any ideas what may be compatible between MySQL and php/OpenSSl?

Comment: PHP/openssl and MySQL are supporting CBC mode

Comment: @MichaelFehr I will look into AES-256-CBC then. Thank you!